# Apps Script - How to replace Smart Quotes characters in Google Docs with normal characters?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-apps-script-addon

I have a problem with Smart Quotes in Google Docs that related to the apostrophe character.

For example, if I type the string `Employee's Name`, it will become `Employee’s Name`

Notice how the apostrophes are different.

I need to find a way to replace all those `’` to `'`, and all other "Smart" Quotes characters using Apps Script

It can be done by using [replace](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function, I guess. But I don't know "what" to be replaced. Is there a list of Smart Quotes characters?

So how to solve this problem? Thanks.

---

*Note: I know I can disable this feature by going to `Tools` -> `Preferences` and disable `Use smart quotes`, but I can't do this way, because I'm working on an add-on*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smart quoting replaces the single apostrophe and the double quote into its "smart" (“smart”, rather) equivalents. More info about the characters used [here](https://www.lifewire.com/typing-quotes-apostrophes-and-primes-1074104).

If you are using Google Docs, you may want to use the [`replaceText(searchPattern, replacement)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replaceText(String,String)) function. See below an example code snippet using this function:

```js
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();

body.replaceText("(‘|’)", "'");
body.replaceText('(“|”)', '"');
```